# XSLT - Transform flat XML nodes containing ID and Parent ID into tree structure for presentation

Tags: xslt

I have very limited experience with xslt, but i think it is the best way to approach a new requirement I've been given.

I have a fairly flat xml structure like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<result name="response" numFound="9" start="0">
<doc>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Root</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>0</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Test2</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test2</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>1</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>3</id>
    <title>Test3</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test3</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>1</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>4</id>
    <title>Test6</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test4</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>2</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>5</id>
    <title>Test5</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test5</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>2</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>6</id>
    <title>Test6</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test3/Test6</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>3</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>7</id>
    <title>Test7</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test4/Test7</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>3</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>8</id>
    <title>Test8</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test4/Test8</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>4</pid>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>9</id>
    <title>Test9</title>
    <url>https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test5/Test9</url>
    <type>Webpage</type>
    <pid>4</pid>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

This is an abbreviated example. The actual data would not have sequential ids and may be from several thousand to possibly (unlikely) fifty thousand `<doc>` nodes.

The requirement is to transform this into a `<ul><li>` list with proper nesting based on the parent id (`<pid>`) of each node matching an `<id>` of another node. A `<pid>` of zero would indicate a root level `<li>` element.

The root nodes would be `<li>`'s under a root `<ul>` element and any children of that node would be placed into `<li>` elements inside a nested `<ul>` under that root `<li>`. This would proceed down through the tree all the way to the most deeply nested leaf nodes for each root element.

I should mention here that I am restricted in my current environment to using XSLT 1.0 specification ... no access to 2.0 or 3.0 in our environment.

I've done quite a bit of reading on this and most signs pointed to a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html,), but to be quite honest, my limited xslt experience makes this technique quite over my head. I've played around with it a bit, but can't get anything working even remotely right.

I'm hoping that some of the xslt gurus on here could help me out a little with this. Ultimately, the above xml needs to be transformed into something like this (again, working with an abbreviated example and need a solution that scales up easily for non-sequential ids, no hard coded ids, large numbers of nodes, etc.):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root">Root</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test2">Test2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test4">Test6</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test4/Test8">Test8</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test5">Test5</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test2/Test5/Test9">Test9</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test3">Test3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test3/Test6">Test6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.example.com/Root/Test4/Test7">Test7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If further info is needed, just let me know in the comments.

Thanks,
BP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "don't" need muenchian grouping here, but you can make use of an `xsl:key` to enable you to look up `doc` elements by their `pid` value

```
<xsl:key name="docs" match="doc" use="pid" />
```

You would first start off by selecting the "root" elements; the ones with `pid` equal to 0

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('docs', '0')" />
```

You would then have a template that matched `doc` where you could output the `li` element. Then, to create your nested structure, you can recursively call this template using the key again, using the `id` value of the current node this time, thus getting the children

```
<xsl:if test="key('docs', id)">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('docs', id)" />  
  </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

Actually, you will need to parameterise your templates, so that you can pass the current "path" to the child, rather than building it from scratch each time

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:key name="docs" match="doc" use="pid" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('docs', '0')" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:param name="path" select="'https://www.example.com'" />

    <xsl:variable name="newPath" select="concat($path, '/', title)" />
    <li>
      <a href="{$newPath}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />

        <xsl:if test="key('docs', id)">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('docs', id)">
              <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$newPath" />
            </xsl:apply-templates> 
          </ul>
        </xsl:if>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tim. Initial testing looks good. I added another 10 or 15 nodes to the test xml i posted above, created another root node with some children ... made it so the children are out of sequence. Everything seems to be working like a champ. Thanks so much. Marking as answer.

Comment: This isn't doing any grouping, Muenchian or otherwise. It's just plain recursive descent, processing the logical tree rather than the physical (XML) tree.

Comment: My mistake. I started off my answer by saying "You need Muenchian grouping...", but somehow I missed out the crucial "don't". I have amended the initial sentence.